# Multiple rewrite url with same pattern

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite a couple of pages with different names but with the same pattern in the parameters. Right now they conflicting with each other.

```
RewriteRule     ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)  category.php?categorie=$1&id=$2

RewriteRule     ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)  product.php?product=$1&id=$2

RewriteRule     ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)  organisation.php?organisation=$1&id=$2

RewriteRule     ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)  result.php?result=$1&id=$2
```

The name of the first parameter is different and should I use as a condition, but I can't get it working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And how is your rewrite module supposed to know how to rewrite by looking at URI like `/abcd/123` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't know exactly what you mean, but should I add another parameter? /categorie/123/456 ? , product/123/456 ?

Comment: Yes that will the correct approach to distinguish each pattern uniquely.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. How should the rewrite rule then be if I add this parameter?

Answer (score 2):

After adding these prefixes i.e. `/category/, /product/, /organisation/, /result/`, you need just one single rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?(category|product|organisation|result)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?$1=$2&id=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```